# How to define a model table name without modifying the model in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-models

A tird-party Django Application is installed in a Django Project and it should not be modified.

The table with the data associated to a model in the mentioned Django Applicaction has a name not expected by the way Django names the tables. By now, the fields names do respect the convention.

If i would be able to modify the Django Application, i'll simply set the *db_table* meta option in the model definition. In fact, the idea of having separated apps is the strong of Django, so one should not modify the apps so easily.

The possibility of changing the table name is not able.

Inheriting the model is not possible because the Django Project have references to the model everywhere.

Another way to ask the question is: where in the code can i **inject** the *db_table* meta option to the model class before it is used to connect to the Database? this is question is based in the idea of the **Python** dynamic power.